# How do I propagate the errors of my time series data through the python/scikit-learn/SVR fit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Normally when doing a fit to some time series data (e.g., a polynomial fit), functions will return an associated error with each fitted point. I'm now trying out scikit-learn's support vector regression (SVR) fitting instead, which doesn't have any such return. There is a handy function in scikit-learn called `validation_score` that can tell me the accuracy score of various fits, from which I select the best one. That's not ideal because it doesn't allow me to continue propagating errors through any subsequent manipulations of the data.

How do I propagate the errors of my time series data through the python/scikit-learn/SVR fit?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Create some fake data
times = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)[:, None]
data = np.sin(times).ravel()
uncertainty = np.linspace(0.05, 0.1, num=10)
np.random.shuffle(uncertainty)
sample_weight = 1 / uncertainty


# Quick helper function
def jpm_svr(gamma=1e-6, **kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=gamma, **kwargs))

# Find the best value of gamma
gamma = np.logspace(-2, 5, num=11, base=10)
shuffle_split = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=20, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, random_state=None)
# In the next line I also want to input the sample_weight but can't
train_score, val_score = validation_curve(jpm_svr(), X, y, #sample_weight :(
                                          'svr__gamma',
                                          gamma, cv=shuffle_split, scoring=evs)
score = np.median(val_score, axis=1)
best_score_index = np.argmax(score)

# Generate model with best value of gamma
# Also note that I can now pass in sample_weight
# But there aren't any direct returns from SVR for uncertainty
model = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=gamma[best_score_index]).fit(times, data, sample_weight)
X_test = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)[:, None]
y_test = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Also, fyi from the faq page over at scikit-learn: *Please make sure to include a minimal reproduction code snippet (ideally shorter than 10 lines) that highlights your problem on a toy dataset (for instance from sklearn.datasets or randomly generated with functions of numpy.random with a fixed random seed). Please remove any line of code that is not necessary to reproduce your problem.*

Comment: I normally do include an example, and I've now done so here.